# Tkinter auto start issue

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gui, kiosk, tkinter

I'm building a kiosk with raspberry pi 3. And using Raspbian Jessie with Pixel. My python program is using GPIOs, Raspi camera, OpenCV and Tkinter for GUI building. I'm trying to auto start my python program, I've tried already:
- Cronjob (It was not successful because of my software needs a Desktop environment, I think.)
- I put my software to /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart. But it did not work. ( I've added @/usr/bin/python /home/pi/example.py to the last line)

So how can I make it work?